# Necesito mandar informacion POST a una pagina y que me redirija a otra

Tags: html

Resulta que estoy trabajando en un formulario donde debo guardar un usuario y un insumo, necesito que la informacion se mande para "listar" para poder guardarla, pero es un formulario de 2 pasos, del registro usuario pasa al registro de insumo de venta y luego a listar, entonces desde el registro usuario necesito que la informacion se mande a listar pero siga en la pagina que necesito que es la de registrar insumo, no se si me explico.

```html
<form action="ingresar_venta.php" method="post" id="form" name="form" onsubmit="return validar();">
   <table align="center" style="font-size: 20px;">
    <tr>
     <td>Rut</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txt_rut" id="rut" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Nombre</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txt_nombre" id="nombre" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Apellido</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txt_appelido" id="apellido" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Telefono</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txt_telefono" id="telefono" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Direccion</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txt_direccion" id="direccion" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Region</td>
     <td>
      <select name="txt_region" id="region" required="">
       <option value="I">I-de Tarapacá</option>
       <option value="II">II-de Antofagasta</option>
       <option value="III">III-de Atacama</option>
       <option value="IV">IV-de Coquimbo</option>
       <option value="V">V-de Valparaíso</option>
       <option value="VI">VI-del Libertador General Bernardo O'Higgins</option>
       <option value="VII">VII-del Maule</option>
       <option value="VIII">VIII-del Bio Bio</option>
       <option value="IX">IX-de la Araucanía</option>
       <option value="X">X-de los Lagos</option>
       <option value="XI">XI-Aisén del General Carlos Ibáñez del Campo</option>
       <option value="XII">XII-de Magallanes y Antártica Chilena</option>
       <option value="XIV">XIV-de los Ríos</option>
       <option value="XV">XV-de Arica y Parinacota</option>
       <option value="RM">RM-Region Metropolitana</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Comuna</td>
     <td>
      <select name="txt_comuna" id="comuna" required=""></select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Correo</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txt_correo" id="correo" required=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Siguiente">
              <input type="submit" value="Cancelar" onclick="location.href='../index.html';"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede mandar información a una página que no se renderiza en el navegador a no ser que se guarde en la base de datos.
La solución que veo a tu problema es que vayas arrastrando valores hasta llegar a la página final, a través de inputs ocultos.

**Ejemplo**:

> *Página 1:*

```
<form action="insumo.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

> *Página 2:*

```
<form action="listar.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="usuario" value="<?= $_POST['usuario'] ?>"/>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```